# Hacer un arreglo de primos y no primos, con bucle anidados

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando crear una función que reciba un array de números y me devuelva un array clasificándolos como primos o noPrimos, pero no logro que funcione correctamente

```js
var arr2 = [1, 5, 2, 9, 3, 4, 11];

function sumaTodosPrimos(arr) {
  var primos = [];
  var noPrimos = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == 1) {
      noPrimos.push(arr[i]);
    }
    if (arr[i] == 2) {
      primos.push(arr[i]);
    }

    for (var s = 2; s < arr[i]; s++) {
      if (arr[i] % s == 0) {
        noPrimos.push(arr[i]);
        break;
      } else {
        primos.push(arr[i]);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(primos);
  console.log(noPrimos);
}

sumaTodosPrimos(arr2);
```

Pero como resultado en primos tengo [ 5, 2, 9, 3, 11 ]
Y en noPrimos [ 1, 4 ]

No sé dónde está mi error, ¿En la iteración donde 9%3 no debería mandarlo a noPrimo y ejecutar el break?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay un problema con el enfoque que estás tomando para agregar números a las matrices primos y noPrimos. En el ciclo for interno, estás agregando el número a la matriz noPrimos si es divisible por s y luego, en la misma iteración, lo agregas a la matriz primos si no es divisible por s. Esto no tiene sentido y los resultados no serán precisos.

Aquí hay una solución para tu problema:

La función clasificarNumeros toma un arreglo de números y devuelve un objeto que contiene dos arreglos: primos y noPrimos. En el ciclo for, para cada número, primero determina si es primo o no. Para hacer esto, utiliza un ciclo for interno que verifica si el número es divisible por algún número entre 2 y su raíz cuadrada. Si el número es divisible por algún número dentro de este rango, entonces no es primo.

```js
    function clasificarNumeros(arr) {
  var primos = [];
  var noPrimos = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var esPrimo = true;

    if (arr[i] < 2) {
      esPrimo = false;
    } else {
      for (var s = 2; s <= Math.sqrt(arr[i]); s++) {
        if (arr[i] % s == 0) {
          esPrimo = false;
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    if (esPrimo) {
      primos.push(arr[i]);
    } else {
      noPrimos.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }

  return {
    primos: primos,
    noPrimos: noPrimos
  };
}
var arr2 = [1, 5, 2, 9, 3, 4, 11];
var clasificados = clasificarNumeros(arr2);
console.log(clasificados.primos);   // [5, 2, 3, 11]
console.log(clasificados.noPrimos); // [1, 9, 4]
```

Comment: Ahora entiendo, para el 9 => 9%2 es diferente de 0 y lo manda al arreglo de Primos, porque se ejecuta antes que el 9%3 que sí es 0.  Muchas gracias

Comment: @Bayes-T Recuerdo aceptar la respuesta si esta te ha ayudado. Saludos